# Make my jquery shorter?

Tags: jquery, toggle, this, parent-child

I'd like shorten my JQuery. I know this is possible using this element and child but I don't know how it works?

I have an element being show and hidden on click basically. They all have the same ID, just a different classes.

How is it possible to achieve this?

This is what my html looks like:

```
 <div id="spotparent">

  <div id="spot"  class="one" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="one">
                    <img src="img/line-boost.png">

          </div>
        </div>

<div id="spot" class="two"  style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height: 25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="two">
                    <img src="img/line-tpu.png">

          </div>
        </div>

          <div id="spot"  class="three" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="three">
                    <img src="img/line-wrap.png">

          </div>
        </div>

            <div id="spot"  class="four" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="four">
                    <img src="img/line-support.png">

          </div>
        </div>

         <div id="spot"  class="five" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="five">
                    <img src="img/line.png">

          </div>
        </div>

         <div id="spot"  class="six" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="six">
                    <img src="img/line-knit.png">

          </div>
        </div>


         <div id="spot"  class="seven" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="seven">
                    <img src="img/line-signature.png">

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

The point is on click of a spot id, the id 'contentspot' show ( by toggling a class who change the display from none to block).

for this I'm using the following JQuery:

```
$('#spot.one').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.one').toggleClass('showcontent');

});


$('#spot.two').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.two').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.three').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.three').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.four').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.four').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.five').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.five').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.six').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.six').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.seven').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.seven').toggleClass('showcontent');

});
```

So it get repeated the all time.

I'm sure it's possible to make all this code in 2 lines, if anybody can explain me the process for me to understand, it would be fantastic!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of: Don't use the `ID` multiple time in one document. This can be lead to errors and is invalid html

Comment: Secondly, as your code is working, isn't it?, your question would probably a better fir for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should take @empiric's advice and only use an `id` once per page at most. `id` should be a unique attribute, not reused. I would recommend something like this, using `class` attribute for similar elements

```
<div id="spots">

  <div class="spot" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="pulse"></div>

    <div class="content">
      <img src="img/line-boost.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- more spots... -->

</div>
```

Then you can write your jQuery function to run any time an element with `class="spot"` is clicked

```
<script>
  $('#spots .spot').on('click', function() {
    $(this) //this refers to the clicked element, our .spot
      .find('.content')  //select child elements with class 'content'
      .toggleClass('showcontent');
  });
</script>
```